# Some folders are created by an unknown program

Tags: windows-7, debian

[image]

This is an NTFS partition and some program keeps rewriting these folders (except *Muzik* which is my own created folder, *RECYCLER* and *$RECYCLE.BIN*) even after I delete them. Do you know how to figure out the source which makes these folders? (I dual boot Debian Jessie with Windows 7 x64)

Each folder have a file like this in them:

[image]

An `ls -ll` returns this: http://paste.debian.net/82233/

Comment: Which operating system is creating the files Windows or Debian?

Comment: @Ramhound Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Try `file` command, it will detect the content in that file. Should be able to give you a rough idea what those files are and who created them.

Or you can try `auditd`, and place an watcher on the directory where those files are created. Here's a post http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html that should help.

Comment: `file` command tells me that they are *data* files (not much help there). I will setup an `auditd` watcher.

Answer (score 0):

IF the unknown program is a linux program you could see some results with one of these programs:

```
lsof /mnt/depomnt 
fuser /mnt/depomnt
```

But why don't you know if Windows or Linux created the files? Just delete them and wait some time in one OS and if nothing happens, change to the other (and look at the creeation time of the files).

Did you look into these files? The `index.dat` and `??/*.file`

**[another test]**
The directory structure looks like some sort of cache (proxy server?). Does the following command show any files apart from the mount files (fstab,mtab)?

```
grep -F depomnt /etc/
```

Comment: I've deleted them and rebooted: it's Debian that creates them. Yes, I've looked into those files and their content is gibberish (http://i.imgur.com/n0NyMWA.png & http://i.imgur.com/FIqDDOD.png). Also both `lsof` and `fuser` return nothing.